# Invalid expression term 'public'

Tags: c#, oop, public, access-modifiers

For the following code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        public int x = 5;
        MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
    }
}
```

I have the following error

> Invalid expression term 'public'

on the line `public int x = 5;`

Why can't I define public objects inside event handler?

Comment: what use is `public` keyword within a method?

Comment: Why `public int x = 5;`?

Comment: i just test declaring public object inside event handler

Comment: sometimes i need to declare public objects inside event handler like ' connection '

Comment: Make `x` class field instead.

Comment: i know, but i ask why this throw error? i anything error

Comment: Not only do you not “need to declare public objects inside event handler”, but that is not possible because objects inside an even handler exist only while the handler is running. If you want to use something `public` inside an event handler it has to be declared outside the even handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public` is an access modifier for types (e.g. `public class Foo`) and type members (such as methods, properties, or fields on a class, e.g. `button3_Click`).

You are trying to declare a local variable inside a method as public, which is not allowed.

One way to fix the compilation error is to remove the access modifier from the local variable declaration in `button3_Click`:  `int x = 5;` instead of `public int x = 5;`.  You should use this if you only need to access the variable `x` within `button3_Click` and you are happy to have a new variable instantiated for every time `button3_Click` is called.

Another way to fix the compilation error is to change `x` from a local variable to a field.  By changing where `x` is defined, you can declare it as a field on `Form1` instead of a local variable in the `button3_Click` scope.

Try:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int x;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x = 5;
        MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
    }
}
```

This option is preferable if you need to access the `x` field from other methods in your program, or you want to preserve values across multiple invocations of the `button3_Click` method on the `Form1` instance.

If these are the case, you could also decide to make `x` a [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) instead of a [field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) in order to gain more fine-grained control over reading, writing, and/or computation of `x`.